# Are all Java Properties' methods fully synchronized?

Tags: java, properties, synchronization

I know that the Properties class is a sub-class of Hashtable. So all the inherited methods are synchronized, but what about the other methods of Properties such as store, load, etc? (Dealing specifically with Java 1.6)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

the [java1.6 javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) says:

> This class is thread-safe: multiple
>   threads can share a single Properties
>   object without the need for external
>   synchronization.

Answer (score 7):

I always found the doc disclaimer misleading, specially for beginners (pardon if it is not your case).

*This class is thread-safe: multiple threads can share a single Properties object without the need for external synchronization.*

Even Thread-safe classes need synchronization more than you think. What is synchronized on that classes are their methods, but often a user uses this classes in a more complex context.

If you only put/get it is ok, but with some more code things get tighter:

```
p.putProperty("k1","abc");
p.putProperty("k2","123");
String.out.println(p.get("k1")+p.get("k2"));
```

This example code only prints for shure "abc123" in a multi threaded environment, if the section is a synchronized block (and even then things could get wrong).

For that reason (and of courrse performance) i prefer non thread safe classes and i get forced to think: is **my program** thread safe ...